# No macOS update after 10.14.3 on early 2015 MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, software-update

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) 3.1 GHZ i7 (16 GB memory, ~380GB diskspace left). It is currently running Mojave 10.14.3. It seems like the latest version is actually 10.14.6, but when I go to `System Preferences > Software Update...` it says "Your Mac is up to date". (Under `Advanced...`, every box is ticked.)

Does my Mac not support the newer update? If it does, how do I make it see the update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2010?locale=en_US

It allows you to download the dmg and you can try to push manually. I think, your MBP 2015 should support the latest Mojave as you have installed its older version already.

Comment: When I try and install I get told "This volume is not formatted as APFS" and now I am confused as to how Mojave got installed at all. :(

Comment: Check this :https://www.macobserver.com/tips/how-to/upgrade-mac-apfs-after-high-sierra/ try to change to APFS.

Comment: After having converted it to APFS, when I try and install the Mojave update it says "Your Mac needs a firmware update in order to install to this volume. Please slect a Mac OS Extended (Journaled) volume instead".

Comment: Then, So there were 2 solutions:

1. Backup the internal flash drive, erase, reformat as HFS+, and run the installer again.

2. Install Mojave on an external HFS+-formatted drive.


Explanation: with the “stock” firmware of a replacement logic board, the installer expects an HFS+-formatted drive, and won’t update the firmware until it can install the OS on an HFS+-formatted drive.

Comment: That did indeed fix the problem, thank you!